# failed to copy database as backup file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Description:

- I am trying to copy my sql database as backup file, once I login, and redirect to `backup.aspx` and I clicked backup button, it prompt me an error output
- If I open directly `backup.aspx` I can copy the database without any error
- I knew that the problem is my database is connect after I login, so it tell me it is being used by another process
- What I want to ask is that anyway can solved this problem ?
- I aim to disconnect from db on page load but I cant make it, it still prompt me the same error

Error message:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Roy\Desktop\backup
>   fyp\10-18-2011\WebSite5\App_Data\Database.mdf' because it is being
>   used by another process.

Code for button click:

```
    string time1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mmtt");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:/SME-Online/" + time1);
    string destination = @"C:/SME-Online/" + time1;
    string source = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data");
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(source, "Database.mdf"), Path.Combine(destination, "Database.mdf"), true);
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(source, "Database_log.LDF"), Path.Combine(destination, "Database_log.LDF"), true);
```

Comment: Probabky you cannot close the connection properly. Please, post the login con where you use, and release the connection.

Comment: It's likely the people over at serverfault.com can answer this question better...

Comment: If the database is being managed by SQL Server, you cannot just copy away the files. You should either check into making a SQL Server backup (create a `.bak` file and ship that), or then you need to learn how to detach a database from SQL Server before copying around the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

Answer (score 2):

You should backup database first and then copy *.bak file as backup, here some code to get you started, of course you can alter that query or filename generation code to suit it to your needs, be sure to check [Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) T-SQL statement help.

```
public void BackupDatabase()
{
  /// this method should get opened connection
  SqlConnection conn = GetOpenedDBConnectionFromSomewhere();
  string dbName = conn.Database;
  string backupFName = "c:\\MSSQLData\\Backup\\" + dbName + "_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak";

  string sql = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + conn.Database + "] TO DISK = '" + backupFName + "'" +
               "WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = 'Backup of DB:" + dbName + "', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;";

  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
  {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```